# Accessing methods from other pages in Ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

Essentially, I have a method that keeps track of the number of items in an array I built. However, I'd like to put this number on the card that I have on the home screen to keep track of the number of items in total, but the code to calculate it is in the actual page where I display the items. I am having trouble referencing methods outside of the typescript file that they're written in, what I want to do it take the array size method, and use it in a different typescript file that links to a different page. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's some code for the respective files:

So in this file I am trying to get the output from the totalFoodAmount method in the Food Page file and put it in the Home Page typescript file so that way I can use it in the HTML for the Home Page.

FoodPage.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RecipeProvider } from "../../providers/recipe-provider";
/**
 * Generated class for the FoodPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-food-page',
  templateUrl: 'food-page.html',
  providers: [RecipeProvider]
})
export class FoodPage {
  isFoodExpiring: boolean;
  listTitle: string;
  listItems: any[] = [];
  groupedItems = [];
  foodName: string;
  quantity: number;
  isSaveClicked: boolean;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
  private recipeProvider: RecipeProvider, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.groupItems(this.listItems);

  }

  totalFoodAmount() {
    return this.listItems.length;
  }

  groupItems(items){

    let sortedItems = this.listItems.sort();
    let currentLetter = false;
    let currentItems = [];

    sortedItems.forEach((value, index) => {
      if(value.charAt(0) != currentLetter){

        currentLetter = value.charAt(0);

        let newGroup = {
          letter: currentLetter,
          listItems: []
        };

        currentItems = newGroup.listItems;
        this.groupedItems.push(newGroup);

      }

      currentItems.push(value);
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FoodPage');
  }

  addItem(){
    let addFood = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add Food',
      inputs: [{
        name: 'title'
      }],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Add Item',
          handler: (data) => {
            this.listItems.push(data);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    addFood.present();
  }

  editItem(item){

    let editFood = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add to list',
      inputs: [{
        name: 'title'
      }],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: (data) => {
            let index = this.listItems.indexOf(item);

            if (index > -1){
              this.listItems[index] = data;
            } else {
              throw new Error("Error, index out of bounds");
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    editFood.present();
  }

  deleteFood(item){
    let index = this.listItems.indexOf(item);

    if (index > -1){
      this.listItems.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      throw new Error("Error, index out of bounds");
    }
  }
}
```

HomePage.ts

The bottom "getFoodTotal" method is where I'd like to get the total so that way I can print it into the HTML (below this code)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AccountPage} from "../account-page/account-page";
import {RecipePage} from "../recipe-page/recipe-page";
import {FoodPage} from "../food-page/food-page";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    //TODO - Delete this later, this is just for testing login.
    window.localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    if (!this.isLoggedIn()){
      console.log('You are not logged in!');
      //this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
    }
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('currentUser')){
      return true;
    }
  }

  showAccountPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AccountPage);
  }

  //TODO - Turn this into the recipe page.
  goToRecipes() {
    this.navCtrl.push(RecipePage);
  }

  loadFoodPage(){
    this.navCtrl.push(FoodPage);
  }

  getFoodTotal(){
    return //Code Goes Here
  }
}
```

HomePage.html
 This is the html file, in the spot where it says "FOOD ITEM VARIABLE" is where i'd like to place the value so that it way it can constantly update as a user adds items to the list.

```
  <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="showAccountPage()">
        <ion-icon style="font-size:30px" name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="card-background-page">

  <ion-card (click)="loadFoodPage()">
    <img src="../../assets/img/MyFoodPic.jpg">
    <div class="card-title">My Food</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">{{FOOD ITEM VARIABLE}} Items</div>
  </ion-card>
```

Also, if whomever answers this question knows how, is there a way to take the list of items that the user has entered and tie it to their specific account(via login) I'm currently using firebase to handle authentication, but is there a better service that will allow me to tie user entries to their respective accounts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Also, if whomever answers this question knows how," please don't ask two questions in one post. Makes it less useful to other people and there may be two correct answers about different topics. A post in SO should be helpful to others, not just to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a service for this. So your method is abstracted as a generic form that can be accessed by both your `HomePage.ts` and your `FoodPage.ts`. I think you just need to be able to pass the `listItems` for the `FoodPage` because there is CRUD operations there.

To make it easier you could store the `listItems` as they are saved in local storage and then in the service just get and then return the value.

`common-service.ts`

```
 numOfListItems():number{
     this.storage.get('listItems').then(listItemData => {
        return listItemData.length
     })
 }
```

`HomePage.ts`

```
 import { Common } from '../location/of/file/common-service.ts';
 ...
 getFoodTotal(){
    return Common.numOfListItems();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the only components that should be children of the page should be:

> ion-header
>
> ion-content
>
> ion-footer

I'd recommend changing your custom header component to:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header'
  template: `
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic 2
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>`
})
```

and then including it as:

```
<ion-header>
  <header></header>
</ion-header>
```

You can look this small efficient post for your issue: [here](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-custom-expandable-header-component-for-ionic-2/)

Plnkr for your issue here is ;) : [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQMUk7aGZkaFR2jYrfXD?p=preview)

Comment: How does this allow me to access the methods of my other class?

Comment: Oops, written the answer at wronge place, jarred pls ignore it, i will remove this answer from here.